# Autoslider: I'm getting multiple slides appear at once when the window isn't focused

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created an auto slider with jQuery for some content but I'm getting multiple slides appear at once when the window isn't focused. I can't diagnose the problem and can't seem to understand what it has to do with the window being focused. Is there a limitation to the windowTimeout function or is this to do with jQuery methods?

Here is an example of the error when all slides are visible at once: [Slider Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqRqd.png)

Here is the javascript:

```
// Instantiate the timeout var to be set later and some variables for the slides
let autoSlider;
let nextSlide = 2;
let maxSlides = 4;
let slideDelay = 5000;
// Slide switch function
const changeToSlide = slide => {
  // Only run if the slide control button selected is not already active
  if(!$(`#slider-container .slider-position[data-slide=${slide}]`).hasClass('active')) {
    // Reset the windowTimeout to stop the slide from auto changing
    clearTimeout(autoSlider);

    // Hide all other slides and set the next slide to fade in
    $('#slider-container .slider-position').removeClass('active');
    $(`#slider-container .slider-position[data-slide=${slide}]`).addClass('active');
    $('#slider-container .slide').hide();
    $(`#slider-container .slide[data-slide=${slide}]`).css("display", "flex").hide().fadeIn(1000);

    // Increment the next slide counter and make sure it loops after the max number of slides is reached
    nextSlide = slide == maxSlides ? 1 : slide + 1;
    // Mutually recursive call using the delay function
    SetAutoSlider(nextSlide);
  }
}
// Slide delay function
const SetAutoSlider = nextSlide => {
  // Set a delay for the execution of the change slide function on a var already initialsed so it can be cleared in progress
  autoSlider = window.setTimeout(function() {
    changeToSlide(nextSlide);
  }, slideDelay);
}

// Click event handler for the slider controls to switch the slide
$('.slider-control-btn').click(function() {
  changeToSlide($(this).find('.slider-position').data('slide'));
});

// Call the slide delay funciton to start the slider running automatically
SetAutoSlider(nextSlide);
```

This is difficult to replicate but I also have a Codepen with the slider code running to do this: https://codepen.io/DanManiaII/pen/poKzGmj

Comment: After multiple tries with Safari and Chrome browser, I can't reproduce the issue. What's your browser version?

Comment: @dolor3sh4ze I'm using Windows 10 Pro and the latest Chrome Version 106.0.5249.119 (Official Build) (64-bit). If you leave it running for a while in an unused window and come back to it while the slider is in its delayed state you should see it.